# Ext JS warning - Duplicate class name 'Ext.ux.AppInspector'

Tags: extjs

I have Ext JS warning in console

```
[W] [Ext.define] Duplicate class name 'Ext.ux.AppInspector' specified, must be a non-empty string
```

But there is no such class name in the code.

Any idea what's the reason and how to fix it?

Comment: "App Inspector for Sencha 2.0 is a Google Chrome Developer Tools extension for debugging Sencha apps". Please check whether you have multiple versions of that extension installed.

Comment: I have just a single version, installed from chrome app store. However after disabling it the warning goes away.